# Write a function longest, which also takes a list ll of lists. It should return (a reference to) the longest of the lists in ll

Tags: python

If there are ties on length,then it should return the earliest of those lists (i.e., the one with the smallest index in ll). Finally, if ll is empty,then your function should return None, instead of a list.
Again, you should not modify the input list(s) in any way. Furthermore, you should return a (reference to) one of the existing elements of ll (or None), and not create a new list.

This is what I have right now but when I run the tests they fail.

```
def longest(ll):
  if len(ll) == 0:
    return None 
  index = 0 
  for i in range(1, len(ll)):
    if len(ll[i] > len(ll[index])):
```

Does anyone know how I could fix my code to meet the problem's requirements?

**HINT:
Here, the “accumulator” is an (index of or reference to—either will work, we’ll use the former in specific Python statements below) element of ll. Compared to calculating the maximum value, the only essential difference is that the condition used to update the “accumulator” depends on one of it’s properties (specifically it’s length) rather than on the value of the accumulator itself. Although the term “accumulator” sounds, perhaps, somewhat strange in this setting, it simply means (always) that the update rule for it depends on it’s previous value (as well as, typically, something else). Specifically, the next
value of the list (reference) is either unchanged or set to the current element of ll, depending on whether the length of the latter is greater than the length of the former. In other words, let’s assuming l is variable of the for loop that
iterates over the elements of a list. Then, at the end of the loop, if we want largest to hold (a reference to) the l with the largest value (as determined by > on the element type), then our update rule would be similar to, e.g.,
if l > largest: largest = l (among the several possible ways of writing this). However, if we want largest to eventually hold (a reference to) the l with the largest length, then the update rule would simply change to, e.g., if len(l) > len(largest): largest = l.

Comment: Can you provide an example please?

Comment: Why `index = 1`? Is that a typo?

Comment: I dont have an exact example. But from my interpretation I would have a list like [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8,9,10], [11,12,13,14,15,16,17]] inputted. Based off this I think I would need to produce a reference to which is longest list within this.

Comment: You should do something after the `if` statement? What should happen if the next list is longer? Maybe `index` should change?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the length of all of the lists, then find the highest length, then get the (first) index of that maximum value and return that element of your original list.

```py
def longest(ll):
    if len(ll) == 0:
        return None
    
    lengths = [len(l) for l in ll]

    return ll[lengths.index(max(lengths))]
```

Comment: This answer is really not in the spirit of the assignment and would probably not receive a passing grade. If you're just trying to find the longest, `return max(ll, key=len)` is much better that this. But the assignment is trying to teach something else.